# Multer не сохраняет картинку при PUT запросе

Tags: node.js, multer

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, модуль `multer` не сохраняет и не загружает файл при обработке запроса PUT, но при этом POST запрос работает просто отлично все работает и сохраняется. Код API практически одинаков, за исключением того, что в PUT я ищу существующую запись в базе и сохраняю данные в нее. 
Ниже код:

```
router.post('/', isAuthenticated, upload.single("img"), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        category: req.body.category,
        price: req.body.price,

    }).save(function (err, Product) {
        var tempPath = req.file.path;
        if (err) return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'Error not saved' });

        var targetPath = path.resolve('public/images/content/' + Product._id + '.' + req.file.originalname.split('.').slice(-1).pop());
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            Product.img = "images/content/" + Product._id + '.' + req.file.originalname.split('.').slice(-1).pop();
            Product.save(function (err, Dbsaved) {
                if (err) return res, status(400).send({ msg: 'Error not saved' });
                res.status(200).send(Dbsaved);
            })
        })
    })
})


router.put('/', isAuthenticated, upload.single("img"),function (req, res, next) {
    Product.findById(req.body._id).exec(function (err, product) {

        if (err) return res.status(400).send({ msg: "Product not found" });

        product.name = req.body.name;
        product.description = req.body.description;
        product.category = req.body.category;
        product.price = req.body.price;

        product.save(function (err, product) {
            var tempPath = req.file.path;
            if (err) return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'Error not saved' });

            var targetPath = path.resolve('public/images/content/redact/' + product._id + '.' + req.file.originalname.split('.').slice(-1).pop());
            fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function (err) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                product.img = "images/content/" + product._id + '.' + req.file.originalname.split('.').slice(-1).pop();
                product.save(function (err, product) {
                    if (err) return res, status(400).send({ msg: 'Error not saved' });
                    res.status(200).send(product);
                })
            });
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: А PUT-запрос точно `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Да используется: https://gist.github.com/khassanov/7d1b58216de710d15fbf1db6937b2f44